# How to use ping command in kernel shell of Vxworks?

Tags: vxworks

I am a newbie to vxworks, and I have a target with Vxworks5.5, one application is running on it. I want to ping other host with local keyboard and monitor or  telnet. After the ctrl+c is pressed, the task is going on after being interrupted for several seconds, and I can see `>-`,which means that it's now in C-interpreter mode. After PING command was entered, I was told that there's no such command.

I read the manual, and know that there is also a command mode. How can I switch to command mode and use the PING command?

Answer (score 2):

VxWorks 5.5 has only C interpreter shell and does not support command shell.
Define `INCLUDE_PING` in configAll.h or in your Tornado project. Try -> ping "8.8.8.8"

VxWorks 6.x has C interpreter shell and command shell. Use `cmd` to switch to the command shell and `C` to switch to the C interpreter shell.

```
-> ping "8.8.8.8"
-> cmd    
[vxWorks]# ping 8.8.8.8
[vxWorks]# C
->
```

Answer (score 0):

If using VxWorks 6.x, switch to the command shell by entering `cmd` in the C shell. There, you can issue command `help` to list available commands. If ping is not present, you can add it via the workbench.

From the workbench, add component `INCLUDE_IPPING_CMD` and rebuild VxWorks on the target. Then you should be able to issue ping commands in the form `ping 1.2.3.4` from the command shell. Typically, to use commands that are not included by default in the command shell, you'll need to add components to your VxWorks project in the form `INCLUDE_`*CommandName*_`CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

One can ping from the C-shell as well. For example, to ping 192.168.1.2 three times:

```
-> ping("192.168.1.2", 3)
```